# Как изменить размер ImageVew при нажатии? При помощи XML разметки

Tags: android, xml, android-selector

Есть `ImageView` :

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="76dp"
    android:layout_height="76dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/camera_change_selector"/>
```

Есть `selector`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_camera_down" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_camera_up"></item>
</selector>
```

Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии @drawable/btn_camera_up уменьшалось в размерах при помощи XML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вместо изображения для меньшего состояния используешь для селектора следующий ресурс -

*camera_up.xml:* (Здесь изображение будет уменьшено на 3dp с каждой стороны)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<inset
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/btn_camera_up"
    android:insetTop="3dp"
    android:insetRight="3dp"
    android:insetBottom="3dp"
    android:insetLeft="3dp" />
```

селектор *camera_change_selector.xml*:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_camera_down" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/camera_up"></item>
</selector>
```

ImageView обязательно должен быть устанавлен атрибут `android:clickable = "true"`

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="76dp"
    android:layout_height="76dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/camera_change_selector"/>
```

Comment: Мне кажется, что в первом xml нужно заменить @drawable/btn_camera_up на @drawable/btn_camera_down.

Comment: @iramm у автора так было, я ничего не менял. Значение по умолчанию - camera_up (оно меньше). при нажатии - camera_down (увеличивается)